# Deposit on bottom beer bottle

Tags: deposit

What is the residue some in bottled (special) beers. Is it true that it can cause flatulence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This deposit is called trub (sometimes lees), and is a created in all ethanol fermentation processes.
The trub is mostly yeast cells both living and dead. This is why this deposit is only seen in beers that ferment in the bottle as it is otherwise removed before bottling. It is even possible to cultivate the yeast from the trub, but this requires special care. It is often advised not to drink it but some people like the taste. It is also possible a little glass is provided to separately drink the trub.

As some of the yeast still lives, it will continue to produce gas while inside you which can cause flatulence.

Comment: Isn't lees when it is in wine and trub in beer?

Comment: lees is a general term and trub is indeed a more specified term (comes from german for lees). I have corrected it.